# React Native - render shadow on view border not on content

Tags: react-native

I am having problem. I want to add shadows to the border of a view, like here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/709

I have tried with styled-components and with normal style prop.

I currently have:

```
const shadow = {
  shadowOffset:{  width: 10,  height: 10,  },
  shadowColor: 'black',
  shadowOpacity: 1.0,
  shadowRadius: 8,
};

...

<View style={shadow}>
  <TotalText>SALDO</TotalText>
  <MoneyText>R$ 1.000,00</MoneyText>
  <NextAllowanceText>PRÓXIMA MESADA</NextAllowanceText>
</View>
```

This is the output: https://ibb.co/b6xOYp

I want the shadow to be applied to the border and not the content inside, what am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean 'not the content inside'?. Try to reduce `shadowOffset`

Comment: @anhtu I want the shadow to apply only to the border of the outerview. Not to the text displayed inside, like it is doing today. Is that more clear? thanks! I tried to reduce the offset but did not work.

Comment: try with stylesheet `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shadow:{
    shadowOffset:{  width: 10,  height: 10,  },
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 1.0,
    shadowRadius: 8,
},
});`

Using `<View style={styles.shadow}>`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try setting the background colour of the view to white - backgroundColor: 'white'